# haskell function given type signature dealing with list

Tags: haskell

```
mapNew :: a -> (a -> b -> c) -> [b] -> [c]
```

Given this type signature, what kind of function should `mapNew` be?

I know the return type is list.

Comment: It's a function that applies the same `a` and every from `[b]` to the function passed as a 2nd argument and produces `[c]`. So implementation could be just a `map` of `a -> (a -> b -> c) -> b -> c` over `[b]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks a lot like a homework question. If it is, I strongly recommend you try and answer this question for yourself. With that said, I'll walk you through how I would formulate an answer to this question and hopefully give you some insight into how you should approach questions like this.

We know that `mapNew` has type `a -> (a -> b -> c) -> [b] -> [c]`. This looks a lot like the existing Prelude function `map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`. So we probably want to write our answer in terms of `map`.

```
mapNew :: a -> (a -> b -> c) -> [b] -> [c]
mapNew a f bs = ...
```

We always start by writing out the function with the arguments it takes so that we can see what pieces we have to work with. Knowing that we only have a single `a` and need to always pass it to `f` for each element `b` in `bs`, we can add a `where` clause for this partial application:

```
mapNew :: a -> (a -> b -> c) -> [b] -> [c]
mapNew a f bs = ...
    where fa :: b -> c
          fa = f a
```

Given this, we can now write our answer in terms of `map`.

```
mapNew :: a -> (a -> b -> c) -> [b] -> [c]
mapNew a f bs = map fa bs
    where fa :: b -> c
          fa = f a
```

Most haskell programmers would simplify this definition to:

```
mapNew :: a -> (a -> b -> c) -> [b] -> [c]
mapNew a f bs = map (f a) bs
```

since `(f a)` is exactly the partially applied function `fa`. Further, we can eta-reduce this expression to:

```
mapNew :: a -> (a -> b -> c) -> [b] -> [c]
mapNew a f = map (f a)
```

The crux of this answer is in the statement "Knowing that we only have a single `a` and need to always pass it to `f` for each element `b` in `bs`". How do I know this?

Because of parametric polymorphism we can't inspect any values of type `a`. This means that the only value of type `a` we have available to us is the one passed to `mapNew`. Further, since `f` takes a single `b` and produces a single `c`, we know that we must first get a `b` out of the provided list in order to apply `f` to it. This is exactly what `map` does, and by partially applying `f` to `a` we get the first argument we want to pass to `map`.